# Travel with existing visa while renewal under administrative processsing

Tags: usa

Indian citizen. Current F1 Visa is valid until July 2020. Need 2 more years of Visa before expected graduation. Have a consulate interview io 15 Dec 2019. If I receive administrative processing, it might be a while before I get a decision on it. Is it possible to do the following: Retain my Passport with existing Visa and travel to the US and send it back to parents when processing is cleared and they can go to the consulate and get it stamped and send it back to me.

Things I am worried about:

Can I send my Passport back to India while in the US for a week: planning on expedited delivery to India and similarly back to me from my parents.
 1. I guess this is more apparent if I can do pt 1: insure the passport delivery both ways.
 2. Does US consulate in India needs me to submit the passport once clearance is received "in person" or can my parents do that?
 3. **Problem with immigration at the port of entry when I use my current Visa while new application is under 221g processing.**

Reason for all of this is that, I  can book a flexible ticket for returning to US but prices can differ by as much as $4000. Any advice in booking flexible tickets w/o worrying too much about price diferences in welcome.

Comment: Okay, I myself found a partial answer from traceldocs website:https://www.ustraveldocs.com/in/in-loc-passportcollection.asp#collectiondocs

It bascially answers the collection part of the question: yes, authorized person can collect it

Comment: Would this question fit better at our sister site Expatriates? If so I can move it for you.

Comment: If you have a valid visa of the same type when you apply for a new visa, the old visa is cancelled.  I don't know whether this is done at the time of the application or when the new visa is issued.  If the former, then your plan obviously won't work.  If I were you I'd wait until after the visa expires, then renew it the next time you leave the country.

Comment: @Willeke please do, I will appreciate that!